# How to make sorting work properly in kendo ui in case of blank fields in Grid/Hierarchical Grid?

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

In case of Kendo Grid there is case when the grid is filled with empty fields as shown in Image. Sorting is altered in this case and do not behave as expected.
My problem is with blank fields. Those should come at the first or at the last while sorted, but these are coming here and there. Any ideas how to overcome this?

Here is what I have tried so far:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#grid").kendoGrid({
        dataSource: {
            data: [
                { FirstName: 'Alphy', NumberColumn: 10},
                { FirstName: 'Betty', NumberColumn: 5},
                { FirstName: 'Ashish', NumberColumn: ""},
                { FirstName: 'Carlos', NumberColumn: -61},
                { FirstName: 'zebra', NumberColumn: -7},
                { FirstName: 'Ketty', NumberColumn: 5},
                { FirstName: 'alpha', NumberColumn: ""},
                { FirstName: 'Loren', NumberColumn: 5},
                { FirstName: 'Brian', NumberColumn: 5}
            ]
        },
        sortable: {
            mode: "single",
            allowUnsort: false
        },
        columns: [
            {
                field: "FirstName",
                title: "First Name"
            },
            {
                field: "NumberColumn",
                title: "Number Column"
            }
        ]
    });
});
```

```html
<link href="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2015.2.624/styles/kendo.material.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2015.2.624/styles/kendo.common-material.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2015.2.624/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>

<div id="grid"></div>
```

[Click here for JS Fiddle for the above code](http://jsfiddle.net/ashishanexpert/pwmtzq81/5/)

Comment: What is your expected behavior?

Comment: Please post your code

Comment: It should sort properly. I mean blanks at the top or bottom rest in sequence.

Comment: @Nicholas, Added code snippet and JSFiddle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sorting looks like a bug because you send `empty string ("")` to your grid. And you can't compare `int` to `string` in this case.

You need to send `null` value to make it work correctly.

**2 Ways possibles:**

**1)** You could perform that by altering your dataSource like that:

```
{ FirstName: 'Alphy', NumberColumn: 10},
{ FirstName: 'Betty', NumberColumn: 5},
{ FirstName: 'Ashish', NumberColumn: null},
{ FirstName: 'Carlos', NumberColumn: -61},
{ FirstName: 'zebra', NumberColumn: -7},
{ FirstName: 'Ketty', NumberColumn: 5},
{ FirstName: 'alpha', NumberColumn: null},
{ FirstName: 'Loren', NumberColumn: 5},
{ FirstName: 'Brian', NumberColumn: 5}
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ghorg12110/pwmtzq81/6/

**2)** You can alter your data into a `schema`:

```
data: [
    { FirstName: 'Alphy', NumberColumn: 10},
    { FirstName: 'Betty', NumberColumn: 5},
    { FirstName: 'Ashish', NumberColumn: ""},
    { FirstName: 'Carlos', NumberColumn: -61},
    { FirstName: 'zebra', NumberColumn: -7},
    { FirstName: 'Ketty', NumberColumn: 5},
    { FirstName: 'alpha', NumberColumn: ""},
    { FirstName: 'Loren', NumberColumn: 5},
    { FirstName: 'Brian', NumberColumn: 5}
],
schema: {
    data: function (response) {
        for (var i = 0; i < response.length; i++) {
            if (response[i].NumberColumn === "") {
                response[i].NumberColumn = null;
            }
        }
        return response;
    }
}
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ghorg12110/pwmtzq81/7/